# Como concatenar um char em uma string?

Tags: c, string

Estou tentando copiar o `char E` para o componente `char` do meu `struct No`:

```
void push(Pilha* p, char E)
{
    No* novo = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));

    strcpy(novo->simbolo, E);
    novo->prox = p->topo;
    p->topo = novo;

    p->tam += 1;
}

typedef struct No
{
  char simbolo;
  struct No* prox;
} No;
```

Entretanto, o compilador me dá o *warning*:

> Passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Queria saber como deixar o valor de `E` em `novo->simbolo`.

Answer (score 6):

Você está a confundir letra com texto (caratere com string).

Em C uma letra ou um caratere é definido pelo tipo `char`.
Uma string ou um texto é definido como um array de carateres e normalmente será escrito como `char[]` ou `char*`.

Para modificar um caratere basta alterar diretamente como se fosse um inteiro ou outro tipo básico:

```
char letra = 'a';
letra = 'z';
```

Agora se tem um texto não pode modificar diretamente pois o texto é na verdade um conjunto de letras (array) e deve fazer a alteração com base na função [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/):

```
char texto[30] = "ola";
strcpy(texto, "mundo");
```

No seu código você tem apenas uma letra mas está a tentar alterar com `strcpy` que é para textos, logo não está correto. Para além disso concatenar significa juntar uma letra a um texto que também não representa o que está a fazer.

A solução passa por tirar o `strcpy` que não está correto e colocar uma atribuição normal de um `char`, tal como `p->simbolo = E;`.

---

Respondendo agora à questão que tem no titulo e que não é o que você quer fazer:

> Como concatenar um char em uma string?

Para tal pode:

- Verificar onde termina o ultimo caratere através de `strlen`
- Colocar o novo caratere na posição dada pelo `strlen`
- Voltar a colocar o terminador após a nova letra

Implementação:

```
void concatenar_letra(char texto[], char letra){
    size_t tamanho = strlen(texto);
    texto[tamanho] = letra;
    texto[tamanho + 1] = '\0'; //recolocar terminador
}
```

[Veja um exemplo desta função a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/kwCuOu)

Tenha em mente que esta função assume que existe espaço alocado na string para o novo caratere, caso contrário você incorre em comportamento indefinido, ou tem que adicionar mais coisas para validar.

Para concatenar dois textos já tem uma função das bibliotecas do C para isso, o [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/).

Answer (score -2):

Em vez de

```
strcpy(novo->simbolo, E);
```

faça:

```
*novo->simbolo = E;
*(novo->simbolo + 1) = 0;
```

Comment: Ao substituir outro erro aparece no compilador:

invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Comment: O campo `simbolo` é um ponteiro de `char`?

Comment: simbolo é um char que está dentro de um no de uma struct apontado por novo. Sendo struct No {char simbolo, struct No* prox};

Comment: Então é só fazer `novo->simbolo = E;`.